# Trying to login to moodle with httpPost but as result i get the same page that i am trying to login. (Android)

Tags: java, android, moodle, autologin, androidhttpclient

The main idea is. I do an httpget request to take the form of login page from moodle. (html code)
Then i find the form params in the html code and i fill them. 
Then i send httpPost request to the login page with the parameters (email and pass)
And in the end trying to get the html code from a new website that needed to login first.
Buts i am always getting the same code . The one from login Page.

I have tried this to gmail and i think it works. I dont get the same code after ther post request at least.

If anyone can help me it would be great becase i am in a little hurry.
Thanks in advance :)

```
public class MyHttpClient {

    private String cookies;

    private HttpClient client = getNewHttpClient() ;

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Chrome/39.0.2171.65";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")


    /* this method is called from the
    * mainactivity .
    *courseUrl is the page i want to go after i login
    */
    public String getHtmlFromElearn(String courseURL) throws Exception{

        String url = "https://elearn.uoc.gr/login/index.php"; //the login page

        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

        MyHttpClient http = new MyHttpClient();

        String page = http.GetPageContent(url);  //gets the html code of login page

        List<NameValuePair> postParams =
               http.getFormParams(page, "mymail@csd.uoc.gr","mypass"); //pasing the email and pass params to post request

        http.sendPost(url, postParams); // sends the post request with the params found in form

        String result = http.GetPageContent(courseURL);


        System.out.println("Done");
        return result;
  }

    /*
    * sends post request with params to login to the website
    */
    private void sendPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> postParams) 
        throws Exception {
        //was getting exception for main thred without this
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        // add header details
        post.setHeader("Host", "elearn.uoc.gr");
        post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        post.setHeader("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        post.setHeader("Accept-Language", "el-GR,el;q=0.8");
        post.setHeader("Cookie", getCookies());
        post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        post.setHeader("Referer", "https://elearn.uoc.gr/login/index.php");
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams,HTTP.UTF_8));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        // THE RESPONSE I AM GETTING IS 200
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        //copy the response page in to a string
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        if(result.toString().contains("login failed")){ // checks if login succeeded
             System.out.println("login faild");
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());


    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    /* 
    * gets the html code from the url given
    */
    private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        //httpget request to get the html of page
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        request.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        request.setHeader("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        request.setHeader("Accept-Language", "el-GR,el;q=0.8");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        //copies response html code to string
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String result = new String();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result+=line+"\n";
        }

        // set cookies
        setCookies(response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie") == null ? "" : 
                     response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie").toString());

        return result;

    }
    /*gets the email and pass and returns a lists withh all the paramas
     * for post request to login
     */
    public List<NameValuePair> getFormParams(
             String html, String username, String password)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);


        Element loginform = doc.getElementById("login");
        Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");

        List<NameValuePair> paramList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
            String key = inputElement.attr("name");
            String value = inputElement.attr("value");

            if (key.equals("username")){
                value = username;

            }
            else if (key.equals("password")){
                value = password;

            }


            paramList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key,  URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8")));

        }

        return paramList;
    }

    public String getCookies() {
        return cookies;
    }

    public void setCookies(String cookies) {
        this.cookies = cookies;
    }
    /* 
     *return an http client that trusts all cerfificates
     */
    public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {

            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `http.sendPost(url, postParams); String result = http.GetPageContent(courseURL);`. Wrong. Remove the second statement. Instead read now from the inputstream like is done in the second function.

Comment: `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`. Remove that and put your code in an AsyncTask or thread.

Comment: @greenapps Hi and thanks for your time .
About your first comment the http.sendPost(url, postParams); sends the post request and print the reponse from an inpustream (just to check if redirects to the new page after login). The String result = http.GetPageContent(courseURL); sends a get request to the new page and returns the response in String format using InpuStream like the other one . So both the lines are using inputstream . Correct me if am wrong . Again thanks for your time . About the second comment i was going to change this :) It was just a temporary solution.

Comment: Ok. I oversaw what your code did. But still it makes little sense to me. You login. Well ok. And if de login succeeds you retrieve another page. But where do you use that you did login? I see no connection. You could as well retrieve courseUrl right away.

Comment: @greenapps I see that i dont login because i print the html of the page and i get the same result . And i dont see any difference in making a request  right away and make it in another function since i use the same object HttpClient client for the requests. Or i am missing something . Something that i didnt mention and maybe i should have is that i am trying to login to moodle . Maybe something is different for moodle . Thanks for your time again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Jsoup.connect and logged in successfully to any web site

```
Response res = Jsoup
    .connect("loginPage.com/login.php")
    .data("username", "myUserName", "password", "myPass")
    .method(Method.POST)
    .execute();

 //This will get you cookies
 Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();
```

And then if i want to visit any other web page i use the cookies that login page returned me.

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("urlYouNeedToBeLoggedInToAccess")
      .cookies(loginCookies)
      .get()
```